# Converting an EC private key to PKCS#8 format using `openssl_pkey_export()` (differing behavior across PHP versions)

Tags: php, openssl, private-key, php-7.4, php-8.1

I'm trying to convert an EC private key to PKCS#8. In PHP 8.1 and up, the `openssl_pkey_export()` function appears to do this:

```
$privateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private('-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----...');

$out = '';
if (openssl_pkey_export($privateKey, $out)) {
    print $out;
}
```

Output in PHP 8.1 and up:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Which is the same as the output from the equivalent `openssl` command:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in ec.key -out pkcs8.key
```

However, when running that same PHP code in PHP 7.4 and 8.0, I don't believe the output is in PKCS#8 format:

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I can't find any PHP documentation that explains what changed in 8.1 for the `openssl_pkey_export()` function to behave differently.

How can I export the key in PKCS#8 format, in PHP 7.4?

Apologies if I've misunderstood something obvious here.